# Keep getting TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, compiler-errors, python-3.6

I'm not sure where my error is but here's the code where i got the error from `index = plottest(doc)`:

```
for doc in plottest:

    for word in wordsunique:

        if word in doc:
            word = str(word)
            index = plottest(doc)
            positions = list(np.where(np.array(index) == word)[0])
            idfs = tfidf(word,doc,plottest)

            try:
                worddic[word].append([index, positions, idfs])
            except:
                worddic[word] = []
                worddic[word].append([index, positions, idfs])
```

Comment: presumably `plottest` is a list, whereas you seem to think it's a function. Can't say more since you don't show us where `plottest` is defined or assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Robin Zigmond in a comment, you are trying to **call** a list, as you would call a function, using the `(...)` syntax. The following:

```
>>> def f(x): return 2*x
... 
>>> f(2)
4
```

Is different from:

```
>>> L=[1,2,3]
>>> L(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The latter doesn't work because `[1,2,3]` is not callable. [The Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) enumerates callable types:

- User-defined functions
- Instance methods
- Generator functions
- Coroutine functions
- Asynchronous generator functions
- Built-in functions
- Built-in methods
- Classes
- Class Instances: *Instances of arbitrary classes can be made callable by defining a `__call__()` method in their class.*

A list (ie a `list` instance) is none of them, since the `list` class does not have a `__call__() method`:

```
>>> dir(list)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

In your example, the first lines states that `plottest` is an iterable. The error shows it is a list. And you try to call it with `index = plottest(doc)`. My guess is that you want to get the index of `doc` in `plottest`. To achieve this in Python, you can write:

```
for index, doc in enumerate(plottest):
    ...
```

Hope it helps!